# ASP Gridview when checkbox is selected store values in array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, gridview, checkbox, arraylist

I have added a checkbox (chkCtrl) column into a gridview, when the checkboxes are selected i want to grab the email address that corresponds to that row and store all the results in a list or array. I would like this to happen when the 'Send Email' button is clicked.

Gridview Code ASP.net

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="table table-hover" BorderWidth="2px" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="GrabModuleID" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField EditText="" ShowSelectButton="True" SelectText="View Student Details" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentNo" HeaderText="Student Number" SortExpression="StudentNo"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="UserID" SortExpression="UserID" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ModuleID" HeaderText="ModuleID" SortExpression="ModuleID" Visible="false" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkCtrl" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Send email button code:

```
<asp:Button ID="SendEmail" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Send Class Email" OnClick="SendEmail_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is very simple. On button click simply iterate through the gridview rows and find the checkbox within each row. Next, check if that checkbox is checked then find the email address and store it in a collection.

```
protected void SendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> emails = new List<string>(); 
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdCustomer.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkCtrl = row.FindControl("chkCtrl") as CheckBox;
        if (chkCustomer.Checked)
        {
            cities.Add(row.Cells[1].Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, tried it out and worked a treat. Efficient way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access BoundFields using Row.Cells[index] in a foreach

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
     Control controlcbx = row.Cells[6].Controls[1]; //control for checkbox
     string email = row.Cells[2].Text; // email text
     List<string> emailList = new List<string>(); //list to save emails
     CheckBox cbx = controlcbx as Checkbox;
     if(cbx.Checked)
     {
         emailList.Add(email);
     }
}
```

verify Cell[index] to match your BoundFields